# Add IsEnabled for just one row in grid (WPF)

Tags: wpf, grid, isenabled

I have a grid with three rows, where I have a checkbox on the first row, and some other controls on the last. 
I want the last controls to only be enabled when the checkbox is enabled. 
I tried the example below, but it's not working. Is there an easier way to do this, or do I have to write "IsEnabled=..." on every single control on the last row?

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" IsEnabled="{DataBinding:DataBinder FooProperty}"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Checkbox Grid.Row=0 IsChecked="{DataBinding:DataBinder FooProperty}" ...../>
   <Label Grid.Row="2" ...../>
   <Slider Grid.Row="2" ...../>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `IsEnabled` property on a `Grid`'s `Row` doesn't enable/disable the controls assigned to it since they're not `Children` elements of that row. However, if you put the in any layout (`StackPanel`, `Grid`, `WrapPanel`, etc.) and bind the `IsEnabled` property of that layout, the children controls will be affected.

Here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="{DataBinding:DataBinder FooProperty}">
        <Label Content="Label"/>
        <Slider />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```